# Column names repeated with v-for loop for nested tables in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My Issue is i have data coming from multiple tables in different variables. My column names are being repeated versus the number of records i have in my table.

i want structure like below for my output -- Every booking should have his details like pickup, drop address, first name, last name , then its payment details column wise -- if user has paid thrice for this booking-- it should display in column such as transaction reference and amount thrice.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Below is my code

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-full1" data-page-length='50'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-center">Created At</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Trip Date</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Trip Time</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Invoice#</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Customer Name</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Vehicle Type</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Trip Cost</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Total Invoice Amount</th>
                                            <div v-for="b in bookings" :key="b.invoice">
                                            <th class="text-center" v-for="p in b.payments" :key="p.id">
                                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <p>Transaction Reference </p>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                Amount
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                </table> 
                                            </th>
                                            </div>
                                            <th class="text-center">Total Deposit</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Remaining Balance</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Assigned Driver</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody >
                                        <tr v-for="b in bookings" :key="b.invoice">
                                            <td class="text-center">{{ b.created_at}}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">{{ b.trip_date}}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                            <p>{{b.trip_time }}</p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <p>{{b.invoice}}</p>
                                            </td> 
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                {{ b.customer_name }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                {{ b.vehicle_type }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                {{ b.trip_cost }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                {{ b.total_invoice_amount}}
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="40%" v-for="p in b.payments" :key="p.id">
                                                <table class="table">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="border-right: 1px solid black">
                                                                {{ p.transaction_reference }}
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                {{ p.amount }}
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                </table> 
                                            </td>  
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                {{ b.deposit_collected }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                {{ b.remaining_balance }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                {{ b.assigned_driver}}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>


and data i am getting in this way

[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzLTW.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwwBM.jpg
```

Comment: Your **bookings** is also an object, that's why you don't get any data/value. Instead of iterating **bookings**, you need to iterate the **bookings.data**.